# Search xPub address on a full node

Tags: bitcoind, blockchain.info, bitcoin-core-development, blockexplorer

I am running a full node & using [bitcoinABE](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe) to run a block explorer.
I have couple of wallets on 3rd party wallet providers where I can do xPub

Similar to blockchain.info xPub search how do I do it on my block explorer, or could anyone explain how xPub search works ?

Answer (score 1):

After understanding what extended/extensible public addresses(xPub) are I found out that I need to generate addresses of an xpub then search the individual addresses tx